# Big O Complexity for this code snippet (c#)?

Tags: c#, time-complexity, big-o

I'm a CS student and I need to calculate the Big O time complexity for the following piece of C# code and show my thought process for each line (as I've shown with comments to the right):

```
int n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());                 // 1

LinkedList<int> sumSequence = new LinkedList <int>();    // 1

sumSequence.AddLast(0);                                  // 1
sumSequence.AddLast(1);                                  // 1

for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)                              // n - 2
{
  int currentSum = 0;                                    // 1

  for (int j = i - 1; j > 0; j--)                        // ??
  {
    currentSum += sumSequence.ElementAt(j);              // ??
  }
  sumSequence.AddLast(currentSum);                       // ??
}

for (int i = 0; i < sumSequence.Count(); i++)            // ??
{
  Console.WriteLine(sumSequence.ElementAt(i));           // ??
}

// Total:
// Step 1: XXX  <- Remove constants
// Step 2: XXX  <- Remove coefficients
// Step 3: XXX  <- Select most prominent
```

My problem is, I can get calculate the Big O line-by-line until I get to the inner for-loop (where I've put the '??').

The fact that there's then also an `.ElementAt()` method (which I know is O(n) ) is throwing me off further.

Could someone do me an absolute solid and help me out here? I will be forever grateful & promise to pay it forward.

Thank you!

- Luke

Comment: `ElementAt(j)` is O(j). And so your inner loop is O(1+...+i) which is O(i^2).  And now the outer loop is O(1^2+...+n^2) which is O(n^3).

Comment: tbh, the information you're looking for will probably be better found in your textbook and class notes. you should already have learned about this in class, no? I can't remember specifics off-hand or I would be more helpful, but the information should already be available in your course documentation (and learning how to find answers that way is one of the most important skills to gain).

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you are looking for `O`, not for exact number of operations:

```
int n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());                 // O(1)

LinkedList<int> sumSequence = new LinkedList <int>();    // O(1)

sumSequence.AddLast(0);                                  // O(1)
sumSequence.AddLast(1);                                  // O(1)

for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)                              // O(n)
{
  int currentSum = 0;                                    // O(n)

  for (int j = i - 1; j > 0; j--)                        // O(n^2)
  {
    currentSum += sumSequence.ElementAt(j);              // O(n^3)
  }

  sumSequence.AddLast(currentSum);                       // O(n)
}

for (int i = 0; i < sumSequence.Count(); i++)            // O(n)
{
  Console.WriteLine(sumSequence.ElementAt(i));           // O(n^2)
}
```

Finally, the overall time complexity is `O(n^3)`